# Test if a date matches an iCalendar recurring event

Tags: javascript, php, icalendar, rfc5545

I'm looking for an [iCalendar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) rule matching algorithm that will allow me to validate if a particular date entered by a user falls on a date that is determined by an iCal recurring event rule.

For example:

- the user inputs `Nov 1, 2014` (assume that I can parse the date)
- the ical event has a recurrence rule of `FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=1` (which basically means that this event occurs on the 1st day of every month)

Clearly Nov 1, 2014 does fall on a date in the ical event. How can I figure this out programatically? How can I get a list of dates determined by the recurrence rule, given a start date?

Any examples or libraries out there that do this?

I'm primarily looking for JS and PHP libraries/snippets, but any type of pseudocode should be fine.

**Clarification**: iCalendar refers to the RFC 5545 Internet Calendaring and Scheduling Core Object Specification

Comment: The easiest way is to use `if` and `==`. So the pseudocode is `if ($onedate == $anotherdate) { dosomething; }`

Comment: @zerkms Where did you get `$anotherdate` from? How did you derive it from an iCalendar event?

Comment: I don't see anything about issues with retrieving the data from iCalendar. If you have any - why didn't you state it explicitly? We need to read your mind?

Comment: Read the question and stop trolling. I've clearly mentioned that I want to test if a date falls on an icalendar event.

Comment: there is nothing about retrieval problems. But I don't care, you could ask whatever you want and however you want

Comment: this is not a retrieval problem. not sure what you're thinking of when I say icalendar. see clarification.

Comment: can you parse (**retrieve**) iCal objects?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11366/discussion-between-anushr-and-zerkms)

Comment: The easiest way is to have a function for that and just use it.

Comment: I'm working on this same situation right now. Did you find a solution poking through the php icalendar stuff in that post down there? When I'm done, I'll come back with some pseudo code if you still need.

Comment: Are you supporting the RFC specs entirely? ByDay, ByWeekNo, etc?

Comment: Thanks Shaggy (or should I say "raggy" :) ), but we ended up not using the spec and just rolled our own model. I initially thought that it would have been best to use the spec for better compatibility with other apps, but later felt the spec was just unnecessarily complicated. We can now export to iCalendar format but never save it into our DB.

Answer (score 1):

for PHP: phpicalendar ([here](http://phpicalendar.net/)), the catch is that the algorithm is not easily isolated from the rest of the code
for JS there is a few attemps but I never checked if they really are compliant enough with rfc5545.

it all depends how much compliance you need: for instance adding timezone support will enable you to address the rare case of countries loosing one day (like Samoa island which skipped from Dec 29th to Dec 31st in 2011).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it's a bit difficult going through the code of phpicalendar, but the answer's definitely in there somewhere.

Comment: alternatively you can have a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyICSParser, not the prettiest of codes but more to the core of what you are looking for